# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Can't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Have an Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

I thought it`s a problem with sessionFactory but can't understand how resolve it.

HibernateUtil.java

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;




import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator; 



public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateUtil(){ }

    static{
        try{
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch(Throwable e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;  
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/storage
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root
   </property>
   <mapping class="main.java.table.Brand"/>
   <mapping class="main.java.table.HardDrive"/>




</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Goods.java

```
package main.java.table;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "goods")
public class Goods {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idGoods")
    private int idGoods;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    public int getIdGoods() {
        return idGoods;
    }
    public void setIdGoods(int idGoods) {
        this.idGoods = idGoods;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

CheckInDatabase.java

```
package main.java.cheking;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import main.java.table.Brand;
import main.java.table.HardDrive;
import main.java.util.HibernateUtil;

import org.hibernate.Session;

/*
 * Класс проверяет повторы в таблицах и если их нет создает и возвращает запись                              
 */
public class  CheckInDatabase  {

    private static Session session = null;
    public static List list  = null;
    public static List<Brand> listOut  = null;
    //List <E> list = null;

    CheckInDatabase(){}

    public static  List isNameInDataBase(String name, String table) {



        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            list = session.createQuery("FROM " + table + " WHERE name like '" + name + "' ").list();



        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if ((session != null) && (session.isOpen()))
            session.close();
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static Brand isBrandInDataBase(String name){
        Brand brand = new Brand();
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            listOut = session.createQuery("FROM Brand WHERE nameBrand like '" + name + "' ").list();

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if ((session != null) && (session.isOpen()))
            session.close();
        }

        if (listOut.isEmpty()){
            brand.nameBrand = name; //если бренда в базе нет, создаем 
            Session session = null;
            try{
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(brand);
                System.out.println("Brand created");
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if ((session != null) && (session.isOpen()))
                session.close();
            }

            return brand;
        }
        else{
            for (Iterator iterator = 
                    CheckInDatabase.listOut.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                    brand = (Brand) iterator.next(); 

                    System.out.print("Id: " + brand.getIdBrand()+ "  "); 
                    System.out.print("Name: " + brand.getNameBrand()+ "  "); 
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    }
            return brand;
        }
    }
}
```

HardDrive.java

```
package main.java.table;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import main.java.cheking.CheckInDatabase;

@Entity
@Table(name = "harddrives")
public class HardDrive {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idHardDrive")
    private int idHardDrive;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "formFactor")
    private double formFactor;
    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private int capacity;
    @Column(name = "interface")
    private String interFace;
    @Column(name = "bufferSize")
    private String bufferSize;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "idBrand")
    private Brand brand;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "idGoods")
    private Goods goods;

    public HardDrive(){}

    public HardDrive(String name, double formFactor, int capacity, String interFace, String bufferSize, String brand) {
        List nameList = null;

        nameList = CheckInDatabase.isNameInDataBase(name, "HardDrive");
        if (nameList.isEmpty()){
            this.name = name;
            this.formFactor = formFactor;
            this.capacity = capacity;
            this.interFace = interFace;
            this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
            Brand brand2 = new Brand();
            this.brand = brand2.setNameBrand(brand);
            System.out.println("BRAND NAME IN HARDDRIVE = " + this.brand.getNameBrand() );
        }
        else{
                System.out.println("this name is in the table");
        }
            System.out.println("Can set");

    }




    public int getIdHardDrives() {
        return idHardDrive;
    }

    public void setIdHardDrives(int idHardDrives) {
        this.idHardDrive = idHardDrives;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public double getFormFactor() {
        return formFactor;
    }

    public void setFormFactor(double formFactor) {
        this.formFactor = formFactor;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public String getInterFace() {
        return interFace;
    }

    public void setInterFace(String interFace) {
        this.interFace = interFace;
    }

    public String getBufferSize() {
        return bufferSize;
    }

    public void setBufferSize(String bufferSize) {
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
    }

    public void setBrand(Brand brand){
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public Brand getBrand(){
        return brand;
    }


    public Goods getGoods() {
        return goods;
    }


    public void setGoods(Goods goods) {
        this.goods = goods;
    }


}
```

AddHardDrive.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;



import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class AddHardDrive extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField nameTextField;
    private JComboBox formFactorComboBox;
    private JComboBox capacityComboBox;
    private JComboBox interFaceComboBox;
    private JComboBox bufferSizeComboBox;
    private JComboBox brandComboBox;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AddHardDrive frame = new AddHardDrive();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public AddHardDrive() {
        String [] formFactor = {"2.5", "3.5"};
        String[] capacity = {"250", "320", "500", "750", "1000",
                "1250", "1500", "2000", "3000"};
        String[] interFaces = {"eSATA", "SATA2", "SATA3","USB 2.0", "USB 3.0"};
        String[] bufferSize = {"2 MB", "8 MB", "16 MB","32 MB", "64 MB", "128 MB"};
        String[] brands = {"A-DATA","ASUS", "Fujitsu","Hitachi", "IBM", "Samsung",
                "Seagate", "Silicon Power","Toshiba", "Transcend", "WD"};
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        nameTextField = new JTextField();
        nameTextField.setBounds(213, 8, 211, 20);
        contentPane.add(nameTextField);
        nameTextField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Название :");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(148, 11, 55, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("Форм-фактор :");
        lblNewLabel_5.setBounds(127, 36, 76, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_5);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Обьем :");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(164, 73, 39, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Интерфейс :");
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(140, 101, 63, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_2);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("Тип соединения :");
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(113, 126, 88, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_3);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("Бренд :");
        lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(164, 151, 38, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_4);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Добавить");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    HardDrive hardDrive = new HardDrive(nameTextField.getText(),
                            Double.parseDouble(formFactorComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()),
                            Integer.parseInt(capacityComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()),
                            interFaceComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(),bufferSizeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            brandComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    HardDriveDaoImpl hddi = new HardDriveDaoImpl();
                    hddi.addHardDrive(hardDrive);


                } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(213, 179, 211, 71);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        interFaceComboBox = new JComboBox(interFaces);
        interFaceComboBox.setBounds(213, 98, 211, 20);
        contentPane.add(interFaceComboBox);

        capacityComboBox = new JComboBox(capacity);
        capacityComboBox.setBounds(213, 70, 211, 20);
        contentPane.add(capacityComboBox);

        bufferSizeComboBox = new JComboBox(bufferSize);
        bufferSizeComboBox.setBounds(213, 123, 211, 20);
        contentPane.add(bufferSizeComboBox);

        brandComboBox = new JComboBox(brands);
        brandComboBox.setBounds(213, 148, 211, 20);
        contentPane.add(brandComboBox);

        formFactorComboBox = new JComboBox(formFactor);
        formFactorComboBox.setBounds(213, 39, 211, 20);
        contentPane.add(formFactorComboBox);


    }
}
```

Error

```
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/storage]
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
мар 11, 2015 11:33:23 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:30)
    at CheckInDatabase.isNameInDataBase(CheckInDatabase.java:27)
    at HardDrive.<init>(HardDrive.java:47)
    at AddHardDrive$2.actionPerformed(AddHardDrive.java:98)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on HardDrive.goods references an unknown entity: Goods
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1598)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1521)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1422)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: So HardDrive.goods references an unknown entity: Goods; what would make Goods a known entity?

Comment: I'm edit the question and added the Goods.
But for the first i want to resolve the exception when sessionFactory creates

Comment: Sure, but it is "Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException"; you have to solve the cause, not the result. Probably meistermeier gave the right answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages says, that Goods are not mapped. You need to add goods to your hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<mapping class="main.java.table.Brand"/>
<mapping class="main.java.table.HardDrive"/>
<mapping class="main.java.table.Goods"/>
```